# DataTable appending to DataGridView, NOT populating existing columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I currently have a DataViewGrid with 5 columns.
When I attempt to create a DataTable and then utilize the DataTable as a DataSource, it is appending to my current view and not updating the existing columns (I can see that the DataTable has the data stored when I step through the code during execution)

How Can I populate the current columns of my DataGridView and not Append the new data?

```
'Select Table Adapter with GetData function
 Dim taRequest As New CSIAutomationDataSetTableAdapters.CheckRequestTableAdapter

'Create DataTable
 Dim dtChkReq As New DataTable

'Populate DataTable
 dtChkReq = taRequest.GetDataByReqIdandlstItem(reqID)

'Source the lstCheckItems DataGridView with the DataTable
 lstCheckItems.DataSource = dtChkReq
```

Preload Image
[image]

PostLoad Image
[image]

Comment: Not sure but try `DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing` before reassigning the DataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I was able to trace the issue back to a BindingSource issue.  Once I created a new BindingSource and assigned the appropriate DataPropertyName fields it worked a charm.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each column a value for DataPropertyName - can be done in the IDE when you click on the Grid and choose 'Edit columns' (in the upper right corner).
The DataPropertyName must match your datatable column names